# Parameter encoding problem with rails

Tags: parameters, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm having a weird issue with posted parameters in Rails 3.1.0.

This is only happening in production and not in development.

I have confirmed that when making a post, parameters are passed to the server as:

> utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=jOn16Uw3oUBPQfX02nt1IN8muZf150nTt24Ic4JgPvY%3D&alert%5Btitle%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww&alert%5Bheadline%5D=%26headline

Which looks like the following when decoded:

> utf8=✓&authenticity_token=jOn16Uw3oUBPQfX02nt1IN8muZf150nTt24Ic4JgPvY=&alert[title]=http://www&alert[headline]=&headline

However, on the server side, the parameters are received as:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jOn16Uw3oUBPQfX02nt1IN8muZf150nTt24Ic4JgPvY=", 
"alert"=>{"status"=>"published", 
          "title"=>"http:&#x2F;&#x2F;www", "headline"=>"&amp;headline"}
```

Obviously, I do not wish to store the encoded values.

I'm using Rails 3.1.0, unicorn, and Nginx.
I have also tried this on a Rails 3.1.0, passenger, apache stack and had the same issue.
In both cases, I'm using 1.9.2p290.

I'd appreciate any advice.  Is there a new production setting that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is a problem with a specific version of Sinatra.
https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/360